# Dash live-update with Postgresql, SQLAlchemy and Pandas not updating

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy, plotly-dash

I am new to Dash plotly and I am trying to use the Live-Update of Dash framework to get data from PostgreSQL every 5 seconds. The web application runs smoothly, but I need to refresh the web to update the graph. I am new to dash and really need help regarding this one.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

import dash
import pandas as pd
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input

import plotly
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go


external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='live-graph', animate=True),
    dcc.Interval(
        id='graph-update',
        interval=200,    
        n_intervals=0
    )
])

@app.callback(Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
              Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals'))
def update_graph(n):
    engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@127.0.0.1:5432/Cryptocurrency')
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        df = pd.read_sql("select * from \"cryptocurrency\"", conn)
        fig = px.line(df, x="time", y="bitcoin_php")
    
    
        return fig
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

**I just updated the code above. I used context manager and reduced the interval to 200.**

Comment: Could it be taking too long to make the request? You could try setting the interval to something longer to test, like 20 seconds. Also, what if you build and destroy the DB connection inside the callback?

Comment: I've added context manager to my code to automatically close the connection and reduced the interval time to 200. The page indicates that it is updating, but the graph does not move. I still need to refresh to see the update of the graph.

Comment: It looks right, based on [this page](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-enterprise/database-connections) from the docs. Can you use a debugger to walk through the callback and see what's happening? It sounds like it's getting hung up somewhere during the DB call.

Comment: I've fixed it. I used dictionary to specify the columns and it's working now. Thanks.